# Jquery Append() Inputs And .datepicker()

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with the form I created.
The form should load one row of fields (Date and issue).
When someone clicks on Date then jQuery date picker should display calendar.
Until this point, everything works perfectly ok.

I also have a button that adds another row of the same fields (Date and issue). The button adding new row works ok but calendar from jQuery date picker is not working in that newly added field.

Can you guys take a look what might be wrong with my code please…

Thanks,

**html view**

```
 <div class="row addmore_issues">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            @if(count($issues) > 0)
                            @foreach($issues   as  $key => $details)
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="hidden"  value="{{$details->id}}"  name="id[]" >
                                  <label for="">Received Date :</label>
                                  <input required type="date" value="{{$details->date}}" name="date[]" class="form-control"
                                        aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="">Issue :</label>
                                  <input required type="text"  value="{{$details->issue}}"  name="issue[]" class="form-control"
                                         aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Issue...">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-1 mt12 mt-4">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm delete">
                                  <i class="fa fa-times">
                                  </i>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                            @else
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="id[]" class="form-control" >
                                  {{-- <input required type="date" value="" name="date[]" class="form-control"
                                         aria-describedby="emailHelp" > --}}
                                  <input type="text"  value="" name="date[]" class="form-control flatpickr-input humanfd-datepicker" placeholder="mm-dd-yy">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                               
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <input required type="text"  value=""  name="issue[]" class="form-control"
                                         aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Issue...">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            @endif
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end row-->
```

**script**

```
     $(document).on('click' , '.add_more' , function(){

 $(".humanfd-datepicker").flatpickr(
            {
                altInput: !0,
                altFormat: "F j, Y",
                dateFormat: "Y-m-d"
            })

        $('.addmore_issues').append(
          `
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="id[]" class="form-control" >
    
    <input type="text" value="" name="date[]" class="form-control flatpickr-input humanfd-datepicker" placeholder="mm-dd-yy">
    
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input required type="text" value="" name="issue[]" class="form-control"
    aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Issue...">
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 mt12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm delete"><i
    class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>`
        );
    
   
    
      });
      $(document).on('click','.delete',function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $(".humanfd-datepicker").flatpickr() method should be called after append() method. 
I will also suggest you to use id instead of class for date picker as user will be adding more than one row, then flatpickr() method will be called again and again, which can create conflict for the element for which datepicker method is already called.